# meaning of "concentrate" in one sentence

Tags: word-usage

I got a trouble in understand this sentence

> On short time scales, clustered cage jumps concentrate most of the nonaffine displacements.

In my opinion, this sentence means clustered cage jumps constitutes most of the nonaffine displacements on short time scales.

I know concentrate means to gather, to focus, to make purer. But I can't find one explanation to match the above sentence. I wonder if I misunderstood the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Concentrate" also carries the meaning of compressing or reducing, without losing any of its qualities. For example, fruit juice may be turned into 'concentrate' by removing the water content whilst retaining all its nutritional properties.

I understand this sentence to mean that 'clustered cage jumps' bring together, or compress, *most of* the 'nonaffine displacements' in a short amount of time.